# How to submit HTML form into a Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've checked around and most things I've found are from 2012 and workarounds for a then-existent bug. Unfortunately I'm not understanding Google's documentation on this very well.

I have a script project that is serving a web page to visitors with an HTML form:

```
<form id="gradingform">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
<input type="number" name="grade" placeholder"100">
<input type="submit" onclick="<this is where I'm having issues>">
</form>
```

I believe that this needs to be handled like any other time getting a script while serving a web page - by using the `google.script.run`. With a form specifically, I *think* that it's supposed to be using a success handler, so for example, something along the lines of

`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(gradeSubmitted).recordGrades()`

`gradeSubmitted()` would be a function that just dispays a message, easy enough by doing some easy div changing. What my real issue is what `recordGrades()` would be like.

How do I pass the form to this function, and how do I collect the information from the form? From there I will be adding it to a Sheet, which is easy enough once the information is in an array because I can just append it. The documents say the form information should be passed as a `Blob`, but Google's example is kind of confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have to do

`onclick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(gradeSubmitted).recordGrades(this.form)"`

And in the code.gs file you will be receiving a json as

`[16-03-25 10:51:51:046 IST] {grade=10, name=Anees}`

Comment: Every time I press the submit button the page goes completely blank/white - as if I were trying to redirect somewhere when I'm doing no such thing - I have the same code for the button as before, with simply the new onclick part. Any ideas?

Comment: It is because of sandbox mode set as HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME. You can apply a quick fix by using HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE. In your doGet HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myfile').setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);

Comment: I invite you learn more javascript and jquery so that you can use full capabilities on HTML services in GAS. :)